# Ansible insert line in file more than once

Tags: ansible

I have a yaml file like:

```
a:
  b:
  c:
  d:
```

I need to insert a line after `b:`, `c:` and `d:`.  I can do this with Ansible's lineinfile module, but only if the line to be inserted is different each time.  If the line is the same (which is possible), lineinfile only inserts it once.  Basic invocation:

```
- name: "Test"
  lineinfile:
    path: "/path/to/file"   
    insertafter: "a:"
    line: "    - {{ item }}"
  with_flattened: 
    - "{{ groups.test }}"
```

Suggestions on how to accomplish this would be most appreciated.

Comment: I tried to do it, but I get the same results as you. Even with regex, if the regex matches more than once, it seems ONLY THE LAST MATCH IS TAKEN INTO ACCOUNT. I've tried a few combinations but none of them seemed to work, sorry. My last attempt looked like this https://pastebin.com/5xnRLJ0M If nobody else comes up with an answer, maybe for this use case, using "shell" module and "sed" command is a faster option.

Comment: "sed" is a good idea.  Thank you for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop is not your friend here, nor is `lineinfile`.  You want the `replace` module.

The following builds the replacement string into a variable, then uses that:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    new_lines:
    - "first line"
    - "second line"
    repl_str: '\1\n'

  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      search_str: '([bcd]:)\n(?!    - {{ new_lines[0] }})'

  - set_fact:
      repl_str: "{{ repl_str }}    - {{ item }}\n"
    with_items: "{{ new_lines }}"

  - replace:
      path: file.txt
      regexp: "{{ search_str }}"
      replace: "{{ repl_str }}"
```

This playbook took this file:

```
a:
  b:
  c:
  d:
```

And made this file:

```
a:
  b:
    - first line
    - second line
  c:
    - first line
    - second line
  d:
    - first line
    - second line
```

This bit of the search string, `(?!    - {{ new_lines[0] }})`, makes the playbook idempotent.